# Spark Dataframe computing percentile on an array

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to compute have a spark quantiles on a numeric field *after* a group by operation. Is there a way to apply the approxPercentile on an aggregated  list instead of a column?

E.g.
The Dataframe looks like

```
k1 | k2 | k3 | v1
a1 | b1 | c1 | 879
a2 | b2 | c2 | 769
a1 | b1 | c1 | 129
a2 | b2 | c2 | 323
```

I need to first run `groupBy (k1, k2, k3)` and `collect_list(v1)`, and then compute `quantiles [10th, 50th...]` on list of v1's

Answer (score 4):

you can use `percentile_approx` in spark sql.

Assuming your data is in `df`, then you can do:

```
df.registerTempTable("df_tmp")

val dfWithPercentiles = sqlContext.sql("select k1,k2,k3,percentile_approx(v1, 0.05) as 5th, percentile_approx(v1, 0.50) as 50th, percentile_approx(v1, 0.95) as 95th from df_tmp group by k1,k2,k3")
```

On your sample data, this gives:

```
+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----------------+
| k1| k2| k3|  5th| 50th|             95th|
+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----------------+
| a1| b1| c1|129.0|129.0|803.9999999999999|
| a2| b2| c2|323.0|323.0|            724.4|
+---+---+---+-----+-----+-----------------+
```

Comment: could you please advice what is wrong here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63843599/reduce-result-datasets-into-single-dataset